# Java Overriding and Overloading throw errors at compile time?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

I have been coding few examples on method overloading and method overridng.
Method overloading is static polymorphism and overriding is dynamic polymorphism.

So any error related to overloading will be caught at the compile time..Correct ?or are there any scenarios when a runtime exception is thrown because of incorrect overloading -- I Doubt

Any errors related to method overriding( -- incase when the child class method has same name as Base class and same arguments as of base class ---- )will be thrown at compile time .

Are there any scenarios in both the above cases where there is a exception at run time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot imagine how method overloading can cause a runtime exception.

Some scenarios when incorrect/incomplete method overriding can cause runtime exceptions:

1. Base method is abstract, while it was not implemented by the child class - this may happen, when the parent class was recompiled adding new method, while the child class was not recompiled (buggy lazy compilation, or classes located in different jars, etc)
2. [Overriden method is called from the constructor of a base class](http://tarlogonjava.blogspot.com/2009/06/calling-non-private-methods-from.html).
3. Related to 1: the base method is not abstract, but the signature was changed, while the child class was not recompiled. So it didn't caused the compilation error and will fly in runtime.

Comment: @Tarlog ..... kool .. the 2 scenarios do make sense .. But these compilation kind of issues might pose same issues with overloading also ..wherin I overload in a child class.Now when i change the base class compile it and I dont compile the child class -- >wat do u say ?

Comment: No. You cannot call overloaded method of a child from a parent, unless you have abstract method, but then it is called overriding.

Comment: Cant I overload a base class method in child class ?

Comment: Well, yes, you can. Let's say you have Base.foo(String) and Child.foo(int), so Child.foo(int) is overloaded. But what then? If you change Base.foo(String) to Base.foo(int) they will become overriden. If you change to something else, they will remain overrode... Well, may be it's possible to think about some case, when it will cause an error in runtime... but I cannot imagine it right now.

Comment: Technically, overriding a class method is called "hiding", and it has different semantics than overriding an instance method.

Comment: @Nathan: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I didn't mean that Child.foo or Parent.foo are static. I mean they are instance. May be I should have written child.foo() :)

Comment: @Tarlog: No worries. I misunderstood, then, because @whataheck asked about "overloading a class method in a child class".

Comment: @Tarlog  If I change Base.foo(String) to Base.foo(char) and compile it and in my Child i have Child.foo(int) ,then thsi should throw an erro at run time ... ?Assuming I dont compile thechild after i change the Base

Comment: @whataheck If you call foo(String) from Child to Base, it will throw MethodNotFoundException. But it is not related to method overloading. But if you don't call foo(String) from Child to Base, I don't see why it should throw exception...

Comment: @Tarlog .. Ok fine ..But my ultimate point is that even the points that u mentioned above 1, 3 etc .. even ther we are changing the base class features and are not compiling the child class ..so why do u think this isnt same as the scenario that I mentioned where a MethodNot FoundException is thrown ..Sry I might be dragging but  I wanted to be clear kind o f.. thnx for ur patience ... cheers

Comment: @whataheck Sure, you can call it "the same scenario". Actually I would call it "the same root cause". I just tried to be in context of method overloading, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

> So any error related to overloading
>   will be caught at the compile
>   time..Correct ?or are there any
>   scenarios when a runtime exception is
>   thrown because of incorrect
>   overloading -- I Doubt

No it shouldn't if your code from the method doesn't throw any runtime exception.

> Any errors related to method
>   overriding( -- incase when the child
>   class method has same name as Base
>   class and same arguments as of base
>   class ---- )will be thrown at compile
>   time .

This is what is called overriding. if its not there then it may throw compile time error if you use `@Override`

Comment: ok if my code throws an exception thts anywayz not related to overloadng .. kooll ...I accept ..  Still my question for overriding is do we have any probability for a runtime exception ..